# unable to start component info android

Tags: android, class

In my android application I use Arabic therefore, in each Activity classes I used a method `addtranslate` and call it when I need to translate text in a Activity. There are about 15 activity classes and I have to write that method and call it. it works well but it is not good practice to implement the method every class I created a new class and instantiate it in Activity classes and try to use it in order to handle translations from one place in the android project.

But I get the following error when I try this.
here is the log  cat

```
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxx/com.xxxx.xxx.ShowMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.xxxx.xxx.AddTranslate.addTranslates(AddTranslate.java:11)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.xxxx.xxx.ShowMessageActivity.onCreate(ShowMessageActivity.java:41)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-18 10:12:26.690: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 11 more
```

here is the newly created java class for translation

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddTranslate extends Activity {


    public void addTranslates(int rid, TextView txt1) {
        String textv = getResources().getString(rid);
        txt1.setText(Farsi.Convert(textv));
        Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/DroidSansArabic.ttf");
        txt1.setTypeface(typeFace);

    }

}
```

This is how I used it in other activities

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page17sub);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        final TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
        AddTranslate tra1   =new AddTranslate();
        AddTranslate tra2   =new AddTranslate();

           if (id == 3) {

            //addTranslate(R.string.butt3title1, txt1);
            //addTranslate(R.string.butt3desc1, txt2);
            tra1.addTranslates(R.string.butt3title1, txt1);
            tra2.addTranslates(R.string.butt3desc1, txt2);

        } else if (id == 5) {
```

can anybody help me to correct this.

this is the latest log after passing currnt activity to addtranslation object

```
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxx/com.xxxx.xxx.ShowMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.xxxx.xxx.AddTranslate.addTranslates(AddTranslate.java:19)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.xxxx.xxx.ShowMessageActivity.onCreate(ShowMessageActivity.java:43)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-18 11:40:46.639: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I still have the problem. I can understand why I can not create a class and use it's object in other class ...

Answer (score 0):

you will need yo use constructor of AddTranslate to send current context in AddTranslate ShowMessageActivity activity change your code as:

```
public class AddTranslate {
public Context context;

public AddTranslate(Context context){
this.context=context;
}

    public void addTranslates(int rid, TextView txt1) {
        String textv = context.getResources().getString(rid);


        txt1.setText(Farsi.Convert(textv));
        Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                                            "fonts/DroidSansArabic.ttf");
        txt1.setTypeface(typeFace);

    }

}
```

and from ShowMessageActivity Activity :

```
  AddTranslate tra1   =new AddTranslate(Current_Activity.this);
    AddTranslate tra2   =new AddTranslate(Current_Activity.this);
```

Comment: @kiriappa : ohh!! friend Current_Activity means your current Activity name

Comment: I tried with AddTranslate tra1   =new AddTranslate(ShowMessageActivity.this);
 but still application crashes , when I go to this acitivuty.

Comment: @kiriappa : plz post latest log

Comment: @kiriappa : what is line number 19 in  AddTranslate.java?

Comment: String textv = getResources().getString(rid);

Comment: @kiriappa : you are using `context.getResources().getString(rid); `line instead of `getResources().getString(rid); ` ?

Comment: @kiriappa : still facing same issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21303/discussion-between--k-and-kiriappa)